# How to make an async autocomplete in Angular 6 (rxjs 6), which does not show any irrelevant data by fast typing

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6, rxjs6

**What i have now:** I have a custom autocomplete implementation, looks like this in html:

```
<input [formControl]="parentFormControl"
       (mouseup)="autocomplete()"
       (input)="autocomplete()">

<ul *ngIf="showAutocompleteList">
  <li *ngFor="let listItem of autocompleteList; let index = index;">
    <a role="option" href="#" type="button" (mousedown)="select(listItem)" [innerHtml]="highlight(listItem)"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

parentFormControl is the value behind the input (the modal so to speak), and is a FormControl. So this encapsulates the text which is displayed in input, and submitted with the submit button.

Now everytime i type or click in input, the function autocomplete is called, and makes a normal async call with subscribe:

```
  autocomplete(): void {
    if (this.autocompleteSubscription) {
      this.autocompleteSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
    this.autocompleteSubscription = this.http.get('url').subscribe(
      (autocompleteList:  Array<OptionItem>) => {
        this.autocompleteList = autocompleteList;
      }
    );
  }
```

I actually do not have any delay for the aysnc call, so everytime user types, I call the backend immediately. But imagine that user types 'Software', I of course do not want to display any irrelevant results. For example we typed 'Soft', and the XHR call is fired. We continue typing and typed 'Softw', another XHR call is fired, before the first call finished its job. So i actually immediately cancel the first execution, since it is not relevant anymore. That's why everytime the autocomplete function is called, i call the unsubscribe of the previous subscription.

**Question:** Is this the way i should implement my autocomplete behaviour? I have seen tooday an artical about the exact same thing, but they implement this behaviour with a detailed (or pure?) rxjs, with Pipes. this is the link:
https://blog.strongbrew.io/building-a-safe-autocomplete-operator-with-rxjs/

I have also seen other examples which are pipes, but they also have in their html for me a bit foreign syntax like '{{ text$ | async }}'.

So i wanted to be sure, whether what i have now (subscribe & unsubcribe) is a good way of achieving what I want? Or should i really change the implementation and implement sth like what they have? Which side has which pros and cons?

And if i should switch my implementation, can you provide an example code with my formControl as model?

Thanks in advance

Edit:

I now have sth like this:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.parentFormControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(1000),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        filter(value => this.myGetRequestCondition() ? true : false),
        switchMap((value: string) =>  {
            return this.http.get('url' + value)
              .pipe(catchError(err => {
                 this.myErrorFunction(err);
                 return EMPTY;
              }));
        }))
      .subscribe(autocompleteList => {
        this.autocompleteList = autocompleteList;
      });
  }
```

Comment: `switchMap` is the RxJS operator you are looking for (you use it to map an (Observable that gives values typed) to 
(an HTTP call), switchMap ensures that the previous requests are cancelled when receiving new words) . You can add a `debounce` on top of that (will "wait" before firing new request, to avoid having 5 requests started when you quickly type "abcde")

Comment: As mentioned in the Blog go for `switchMap`

Comment: and why does not my current implementation give me the same result with the use of unsubscribe?

Comment: @akcasoy gimme couple of mins i am composing an answer which would mostly gonna answer all your question

Comment: @akcasoy have a look at my answer and lemme know if you need any other help

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ReactiveForms then the best way is to watch valuechange of formcontrol.

```
this.parentFormControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      switchMap((value) => this.http.get('url').pipe(catchError(err => of([]))))
    ).subscribe(autocompleteList => this.autocompleteList = autocompleteList);
```

when the source Observable emits switchMap cancel any previous subscriptions of the inner Observable. Whenever a new value will be type by user then switchMap will cancel its inner subscription (network call in this case).

According to your new code this will be solution.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.parentFormControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(1000),
        switchMap((value: string) =>  {
          if (this.condition()) {
            return this.http.get('url' + value).pipe(catchError(err => of([])));
          }
          return of([]); // or of(this.autocompleteList)
        }))
      .subscribe(autocompleteList => {
        this.autocompleteList = autocompleteList;
      });
  }
```

Comment: i have edited the question. can you please tell me if that looks ok? still behaves strange though.. for example when i remove the last char, the browser freezes strangely.. do u know how can i add a condition to switchmap? sth like value !== null && value.length > 3

Comment: switchMap should always return a observable. In your case you added a condition if condition will fail it will not return anything and this will throw error. I edit my code my code for you.

Comment: This solution is partially correct cuz u have not taken care of error handling which is darn crucial in this case if inner Observable chain dies the whole Observable stream will die I suggest you to modify your code

Comment: I have updated my recent code..  The application works OK, but i get 'occasionally' this error from the unittests:   You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable. thrown". Since this part of application is in a very central location, this component will be initialised very often.. But i am not sure in which case i get this error..

Comment: Just remove filter from pipe and send empty array in error case. In error case you already called your method to do some task. I don't think you need filter here. In empty array case you can also skip assignment of result by adding condition in your subscribe

Answer (score 2):

Reactive form instances like `FormGroup` and `FormControl` have a `valueChages` method that returns an `observable` that emits the latest values. You can therefore subscribe to `valueChanges` to update instance variables or perform operations.

> So i wanted to be sure, whether what i have now (subscribe &
>   unsubcribe) is a good way of achieving what I want?

There is not anything wrong with your approach but working with observable will let you use `RxJs` Operators which makes your job easier when it comes to maintaing,testing and what not.

> `valueChanges` returns an `observable`, ***the sky is pretty much the
>   limit in terms of what you can do with the values that are emitted***.

**Error Handling.**

Whenever Value of `formControl` Changes `switchMap()` creates a brand new ajax observable.if you get a 404 from your server the error is propagated from inner to outer Chain and whole Streams Die.

To keep it alive you need to shield the main `observer`chain.
and to isolate the main observer chain use `catchError()` operator with switchMap() .

`switchMap()` does not care if inner `Observable` has completed it will only complete when outer `Observable` has completed.
Even though inner Observable chain dies,outer Observable chain stays alive because error handler has not been called for outer Observable chain.

Apart from this if your input Control is filled and again emptied `formcontrol` will pickup the changes and send a request even though its empty you can take advantage of **[`filter`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/filter.html)** operator which Emits values that pass the provided condition and **[`distinctUntilChanged`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/distinctuntilchanged.html)** which  Only emits when the current value is different than the last.

Here is the Solution.:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
        this.parentFormControl.valueChanges
          .pipe(
            debounceTime(1000),
            distinctUntilChanged(),
            filter(value=>value? true: false),
            switchMap((value)=>this.http.get('url' + value).pipe(catchError(() => {return empty()}))
            ))
          .subscribe(autocompleteList => {
            this.autocomplete= autocompleteList;
          });
      }
```

**[`Live Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fzt1yp)**

Comment: by the way, 'EMPTY' constant is the new way of doing 'empty()' since empty function is deprecated.  -> empty() @deprecated Deprecated in favor of using EMPTY constant.

Comment: thank you for the extension. But i still have this state: The application works OK, but i get 'occasionally' this error from the unittests: 'Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined thrown'. Since this part of application is in a very central location, this component will be initialised very often.. and somehow somewhere here i get this error.. I will update my last code status in the question

Comment: @akcasoy Fine i will look into the issue if you can reproduce the same on my stackblitz and thanx for the update on deprecation of `empty()`:)

Comment: if i could reproduce the issue, i would not write here :) instead i would fix it..  as said before, this component is initialised in my case very often. And i have many many unittests.. and everytime i run the tests, another test fails due to the "Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined thrown". As it needs to have a null or undefined check somewhere in this chain...

Comment: @akcasoy how did you get rid of the error? by using `filter` operator?? apart from it mark it if it is the correct solution or feel free to modify it so that it will be helpful for others:)

Comment: it was another irrelevant point in code :) but i may have another question if you can answer.. can i run some logic between distinctUntilChanged and filter? And maybe some logic in case filter answers 'false'? Currently, in case my condition does not fit, i exit the whole chain, i would like to run some log for example.. before filter as well as after filter rejection.  is it possible?

Comment: @akcasoy perhaps you are looking for [tap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/do.html) operator

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181484/discussion-between-akcasoy-and-vikas).